# Why my bicycle's rear wheel is lifted when I use the front brakes HIGHER if I drive slowly?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

This happens when I ride really slowly, almost the slowest I can.  But if I brake with the front brake while riding medium-fast speed it never happens, which is quite counter-intuitive... Just to be clear I'm not interested in the lifting of the wheel.

I guess that I can be more alert when riding fast but it feels that there is also some physics in it.

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean by going up?  You mean going up a curb?

Comment: @QuIcKmAtHs He's talking about doing an endo.

Comment: What is an endo?

Comment: @JEB what is an endo?

Comment: @ QuIcKmAtHs see picture

Comment: It’s probably because of the reverse torque generated by braking

Comment: That’s one way or else, you could think if the center of mass is above the brakes, due to inertia while braking, the front axle will act as a pivot, causing the lifting of the back wheel(this argument only applies if the CM is above the brakes)

Comment: @ physics2000 I ask what is the effect of the speed.

Comment: You've blowned me away... I don't know how your bike is, but mine is intuitive: it lifts when I go fast...

Comment: Probably because are sub-consciously leaning forward to keep your balance

Comment: @OMGsh well the more your speed, the longer you have to brake, the longer time the torque will act. The lesser the speed, the less time the torque will act. Before even the bike leans in front you have reduced your speed to 0.

Comment: That bike in drawing: blech. Disc in front, caliper in back. Front shock/hard tail and a non-clamping seat? Ridick.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the rear wheel lifting higher at lower speed is not a recognised physical phenomenon, it is induced by the cyclist. See [this video description](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytMOPknZeIo) in which it is explained that you will do an "endo" if you brake hard at high speed and don't "feather" your brakes. The effect is enhanced by throwing your weight forward.

Comment: See also the [site you got your image from](https://www.wikihow.com/Do-a-Stoppie-on-a-Mountain-Bike), which at Step 6 advises that *The faster you go, and the quicker you shift your weight forward, the higher the rear wheel will lift.*

Comment: For those interested, there is a Stack Exchange site about [bicycles.se].

Answer (score 1):

I think you have more (de)acceleration at low speed. With a descent disc brake you can lock (w/o skid) the front wheel at walking speed--instantly-- and you jerk right over the bars. At high speed you're dumping energy into the disc, but not losing momentum as fast. Remember:

$$ \frac{dE}{dp} = \frac p m $$

Really, you should measure this with the accelerometer in the phone to verify that $\dot p$ goes up as you slow down.

Also: having done *hundreds* of endos ((back)END Over (front) end crash), I really think their is a psychological component--anyone with any bike skills whatsoever is going to unconsciously set their CM lower and back when jamming on the front brake at 30 mph, even if they are trying not to.

Comment: Your answer doesn’t answer why does the bike lean forward when you brake hard?

Comment: The psychological factor is probably part of it. However I didn't understand the first explanation..

Comment: @OMGsh It takes a lot more energy (heat into the brakes) to go from 33 mph to 30 mph compare with 3 mph to 0 mph. I think you may lose energy faster when max braking at high speed, but you don't lose momentum faster--so the max deceleration is at low speed, so the max torque to throw you over the bars is at low speed. Still: I would like to see some measurements.

Comment: @ JEB This is because enrgy is proportional to v square?

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that at high speed a bike is more likely to slip and therefore lose some energy to friction. Hence, less energy is left to lift it.

Comment: I am not sure but it might be that my bike slips to some extent while braking in fast speed.